# Append NSMutableData with JSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, json, swift

The server needs a variable named json with a value of a json object. How do I take the json object and assign it to a variable json, and then post it to the server? I have googled this problem and I found the code but its in objective c

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSData *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&jsonError];
if (!jsonError) {
    NSMutableData *postBody = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[@"json=" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:jsonObject];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:theURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
}
```

I am doing this in swift

```
 func post() {
         let url:String = "http://example.com/test.php"

        //-----here i have tried
        let json:String = "json=";
        let jsonString = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       //----end trying---------------- 

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
         let params = ["email":"jameson", "password":"password"] as Dictionary<String, String>

        //let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        do {

            let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)
            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print("dataString is  \(dataString)")
            request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)


        } catch {
            //handle error. Probably return or mark function as throws
            print(error)
            return
        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            // handle error
            guard error == nil else { return }

            print("Response: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Body: \(strData)")

            let json: NSDictionary?
            do {
                json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            } catch let dataError {
                // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
                print(dataError)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
                // return or throw?
                return
            }


            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                let success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
                print("Succes: \(success)")
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }


}
```

I have tried to declare a string with a value of `"json="` but after this I don't know how can I make `NSMUTABLEDATA`, append it into `NSJSONSerialization` and then setting the mutable data into requestbody in Swift if that is what I have to do to accomplish my task

Comment: how did you try to do it? you have the `postBody` code to work from

Comment: sorry I didn't get you. could you please explain a bit more.. @Wain

Comment: if the sample code in obj-c there is a part for `postBody`, you know that's what you need to replicate in swift, give it a try